# How can I have pinentry ask if a password should be remembered?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent, pinentry

In [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79421), the password prompt for gpg-agent includes options for how long the password should be remembered.

[image: neirbowj's pinentry]

However, in my system I get a much simpler prompt, without that option

[image: my pinentry]

How can I get a the more full featured password prompt? I think it might have to do with changing the pinentry program gpg-agent uses from pinentry-gtk-2 to something else. What alternative program can I use instead of pinentry-gtk here?

Comment: You can configure the cache time in `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`, see `man gpg-agent | less -p cache` for the options....

Comment: I was thinking more about changing `pinentry-program`. Do you know whats the one that shows up in the first picture?

Comment: It looks like a Gnome thing...