# Why does gpg ask for password even with gpg-agent?

Tags: gpg-agent

I started gpg-agent as follows:

```
eval `gpg-agent --daemon --preset`
```

and in this terminal window, used the gpg-preset-passphrase command as recommended:

```
echo secretpassword | /usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset KEYGRIPID
```

I then used [this answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71135/how-can-i-find-out-what-keys-gpg-agent-has-cached-like-how-ssh-add-l-shows-yo) to verify the password was indeed correctly cached:

```
echo 'GET_PASSPHRASE --no-ask KEYGRIPID Err Pmt Des'|gpg-connect-agent |
  perl -pe 's/([0-9a-fA-F]{2})/chr(hex $1)/eg'
```

When I now run gpg to sign or encrypt something, I get prompted for a password. This should not happen.

```
gpg -u KEYGRIPID --clearsign --batch somefile.txt

<curses-based prompt>
```

Once I enter the password correctly, and re-run the gpg-sign command, I do not get prompted. This indicates that the password is cached, albeit differently.

gpg version 2.0.14

Answer (score 1):

It's not the *keygripid* but the *fingerprint* of the key. [Here is the reference](https://lists.gnupg.org/pipermail/gnupg-users/2010-January/037876.html). Here's a fugly perl script to help you extract the needed values:

```
gpg -K --fingerprint | 
perl -lne '$/="\n\n"' \
 -e if ( ($len,$grip,$fp)=/^sec\s+(\w+)\/([0-9A-Z]+).* fingerprint = (.*?)\s+uid\s/ms)' \
 -e { $fp =~ s/\s*//g; print "$grip $fp";}'
```

outputs:

```
EF2141BE 24C5202D6905CB0A5C94AB36134E3618EF6141B8
1BA3D65B 484EE4F3DC2595FAF91F51A9731342954BAFD753
```

Copy the 2nd column and pass that into the preset command

```
echo secretpassword | /usr/libexec/gpg-preset-passphrase --preset
```

Comment: `bash: syntax error near unexpected token '('`