# gpg-agent is running, but I'm always prompted for password

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

When I run gpg2, I'm prompted for a password every time I use it.
Based on my reading of the `gpg-agent` man pages, I should only be
prompted the first time.

```
gpg-agent  is a daemon to manage secret (private)
keys independently from any proto-col. It is
used as a backend for gpg and gpgsm as well as
for  a  couple  of other utilities.

The agent is automatically started on demand
by gpg, gpgsm, gpgconf, or gpg-connect-agent.
Thus there is no reason to start it manually.

...

--default-cache-ttl n
    Set the time a cache entry is valid to n
    seconds.  The default  is  600  sec- onds.
    Each  time a cache entry is accessed, the
    entry's timer is reset.  To set an entry's
    maximum lifetime, use max-cache-ttl.

--max-cache-ttl n
    Set the maximum time a cache entry is valid
    to n seconds.  After this time  a cache
    entry will be expired even if it has been
    accessed recently or has been set using
    gpg-preset-passphrase.  The default is 2
    hours (7200 seconds).
```

If I'm reading this correctly, invoking `gpg2` should prompt for a password the first time that I use it, then, If I run it again in the next 600 seconds, I won't be prompted again. Running

```
gpg2 --export-secret-keys --armor john.doe@example.com > /dev/null
```

gives me this:

```
┌─┐
│ Please enter the passphrase to export the OpenPGP secret key:  │
│ "John Doe (asdf) <john.doe@example.com>"                       │
│ 2048-bit RSA key, ID EB7B49EAD38DE665,                         │         
│ created 2018-10-09.                                            │         
│                                                                │         
│                                                                │         
│ Passphrase: _ │
│                                                                │         
│         <OK>                                    <Cancel>       │
└─┘
```

A quick `ps aux` shows that `gpg-agent` is running:

```
ps aux | grep gpg-agent
jdoe   14089  0.1  0.1 100884  3588 ?        SLs  18:50   0:07 /usr/bin/gpg-agent --supervised
```

Alas, running  running  `gpg2 --export-secret-keys...` again immediately thereafter prompts me for a password again.

A few more details:

- I'm using `pinentry-curses`
- I've got `$GPG_TTY` exported in my `.bashrc`
- `gpg2 --version -> gpg (GnuPG) 2.2.4`
- I've read through [Why does gpg ask for password even with gpg-agent?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/310888/why-does-gpg-ask-for-password-even-with-gpg-agent) and [How can I find out what keys gpg-agent has cached? (like how ssh-add -l shows you cached ssh keys)](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71135/how-can-i-find-out-what-keys-gpg-agent-has-cached-like-how-ssh-add-l-shows-yo) , but I didn't *quite* follow.

Comment: Do you have `GPG_AGENT_INFO` set? What happens if you do `gpg2 --use-agent --export-secret-keys ....`

Comment: `$GPG_AGENT_INFO` was not set, but @Kusalananda was correct. Other `gpg2` commands worked without prompting for a password.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the GnuPG 2.2.4 manual, regarding `--export-secret-keys` (specifically):

> GnuPG may ask you to enter the passphrase for the key.  This is
>   required, because the internal protection method of the secret
>   key is different from the one specified by the OpenPGP protocol.