# Is it possible to check for the presence of a cached GPG key without modifying the GPG timer?

Tags: gpg, gpg-agent

I only know [a way](https://demu.red/blog/2016/06/how-to-check-if-your-gpg-key-is-in-cache/)* of getting the information of the presence of a cached GPG passphrase, that is, to run

```
$ gpg-connect-agent 'keyinfo --list' /bye
S KEYINFO 01B3BE66C2EAC153C4ED25F01FEE13D356EF289F D - - 1 P - - -
S KEYINFO 08933C3EB4D922575AF88298E09B770F66C56BFA D - - - P - - -
```

in which the `1` next to the `P` indicates the presence of the key with the corresponding keygrip in the cache.

The problem with this method is that the command above resets the entry's timer of the agent, which is a "problem" when one wants to check the availability of the cached passphrase every few seconds without resetting the timer along with each check.
To be clear, a consequence of this behavior is that if the frequency of the check is higher than `default-cache-ttl`** seconds, then the cache will never be discard before `max-cache-ttl` seconds.

Is there a way to check if the key is in the cache without resetting the timer?

* I also tried the method in https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/79421/70214, but I could not make it work.

** For extra info, see section referring to `--default-cache-ttl` in the manpage of `gpg-agent`.