# Bash script for sending passphrase to unlock OpenPGP secret key

Tags: git, openpgp

Ubuntu 22.04.1 LTS

When I do a `git push REMOTE` after a reboot, after a few seconds it comes up with a dialog box:

```
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
| Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key: |
| "user"                                                        |
| 3072-bit RSA key, ID FF3B0094D97228,                          |
| created 2023-09-22 (main key ID 9BD967C9E4EC49).              |
|                                                               |
|                                                               |
| Passphrase: _________________________________________________ |
|                                                               |
|         <OK>                                   <Cancel>       |
+---------------------------------------------------------------+
```

How can I automate entering this passphrase via a script so I do not have to do it manually?

I tried this which does not work:

```
git push REMOTE 
sleep 10  # Waits 10 seconds.
KEY
```

Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add your operating system.

Answer (score 1):

Firstly : The "expect" way is not safe, I would recommend using the gpg-agent.

If you work with gpg you must have a gpg-agent running while you try to decrypt/encrypt files ( I don't know what you're trying to do exactly when git pushing but I guess you work with gpg files)

Edit `~/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

With these values for one day :

```
default-cache-ttl 86400
max-cache-ttl 86400
```

Doing this, you will just have to enter the key once a day (or at the first push and then it will be ok)

source:
https://superuser.com/questions/624343/keep-gnupg-credentials-cached-for-entire-user-session

To be complete, you can even place at your start session a file decryption, gpg show or something like this in order to enter the key once and activate the gpg-agent for rest of the day.

Comment: So at the minute I only have to enter the key after a reboot, then after that it's fine until the next reboot. I'm trying to find a way to enter it via a script after the reboot, rather than manually.

Answer (score 0):

This is a method of caching the initial password for a gpg key. It can be adapted for automation purposes. I tried using `expect` and `gpg-agent` which was fruitless.

### terminal 1

- setup `socat` to create pseudo tty

```bash
socat -d -d pty,link=/tmp/socat1,raw,echo=0 pty,link=/tmp/socat2,raw,echo=0
# 2023/12/30 10:53:02 socat[1869865] N PTY is /dev/pts/33
# 2023/12/30 10:53:02 socat[1869865] N PTY is /dev/pts/34
# 2023/12/30 10:53:02 socat[1869865] N starting data transfer loop with FDs [5,5] and [7,7]
```

- This is running in a loop.

### terminal 2

- export the tty for `gpg` and run the command which generates the password prompt. Here I'm directly using `gpg`. In your case `git` was generating the prompt.

```bash
export GPG_TTY=/tmp/socat1
gpg -d --homedir $HOME/.gnupg/ --quiet --yes --compress-algo=none --no-encrypt-to --batch --use-agent /path/to/gpgKey.gpg # command to elicit gpg prompt
```

- the `gpg` command is waiting to read stdin.

### terminal 3 (optional)

```bash
file /tmp/socat2
# /tmp/socat2: symbolic link to /dev/pts/34
file /dev/pts/34
# /dev/pts/34: character special (136/34)
cat /tmp/socat2
# Please enter the passphrase to unlock the OpenPGP secret key:
# "REDACTED"
# 4096-bit RSA key, ID REDACTED
# created REDACTED (main key ID REDACTED).
# Passphrase:
```

- `cat` is blocked waiting to print the socket content
- `/tmp/socat2` is a link to `/dev/pts/34` which is a char device so it acts like `tail` rather then exiting after printing the content.

### terminal 4

- send your password to `gpg` command run previously.

```bash
cat > /tmp/socat2
# Type your password.
```

- Don't use echo. Your password will be cached in your bash history.

or you can accomplish this programmatically in python

```py
import pathlib

with pathlib.Path('/tmp/socat2').open('w', encoding='utf8') as fp:
    fp.write('password\n')
```

## cat `$HOME/.gnupg/gpg-agent.conf`

```
default-cache-ttl 120
max-cache-ttl 999999999
no-allow-external-cache
no-grab

pinentry-timeout 25
pinentry-program /usr/bin/pinentry-tty
```

Comment: Tangentially related [How can I find out what keys gpg-agent has cached?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/71135/how-can-i-find-out-what-keys-gpg-agent-has-cached-like-how-ssh-add-l-shows-yo)